# Why does the deserialization return null?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

I am trying to deserialize the response from the [SteamAPI](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamApps#GetAppList) in C# .NET 7. I make the REST request via [RestSharp](https://restsharp.dev/serialization.html#json) and save the content as a file. Later I load the file and want to deserialize it to search it with LINQ. But with various options of [JsonSerializerOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions?view=net-7.0) it does not work. The `SteamAppList.AppList` is always null.

For the data model I used [Json2Csharp](https://json2csharp.com) and Jetbrains Rider.

I tried different JsonSerializerOptions and did debugging via vscode and Jetbrains Rider.

Here is my model (SteamAppList.cs):

```
[Serializable]
    public class SteamAppList
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("applist")]
        public Applist Applist;
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class Applist
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("apps")]
        public List<App> Apps;
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class App
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("appid")]
        public int Appid;

        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string Name;
    }
```

And my SteamApps.cs for the request and the deserialisation:

```
public class SteamApps
    {
        private readonly CancellationToken cancellationToken;

        private async Task<RestResponse> GetSteamApps()
        {
            var client = new RestClient();
            var request = new RestRequest("https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/");
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
            request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "Major GSM");
            var response = await client.GetAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            return response;
        }

        public bool RetireveAndSaveSteamApps()
        {
            var path = FileModule.GetDirectoryPath(MajorGsmLibrary.ApplicationDirectory.Games);
            var fileName = "steam.library.json";
            RestResponse restResponse = GetSteamApps().Result;
            
            try
            {
                File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(path, fileName), restResponse.Content);
            }
            catch (IOException exception)
            {
                LogModule.WriteError("Could not write steam libarary file!", exception);
                return false;
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException exception)
            {
                LogModule.WriteError("Missing data for steam library file", exception);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public static string CheckGameAgainstSteamLibraryWithAppId(string appId)
        {
            var path = FileModule.GetDirectoryPath(MajorGsmLibrary.ApplicationDirectory.Games);
            var fileName = "steam.library.json";
            var fileData =
                File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(path, fileName));
            SteamAppList? steamAppList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SteamAppList>(fileData, new JsonSerializerOptions { MaxDepth = 64, Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping });

            if (steamAppList!.Applist != null)
            {
                var app = steamAppList.Applist.Apps.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Appid.ToString() == appId);
                if (app != null) return app.Name;
            }

            return "Unknown";
        }
    }
```

Im calling the SteamApps-class from a GTK# Application:

```
foreach (var game in Games)
            {
                var appName = SteamApps.CheckGameAgainstSteamLibraryWithAppId(game.AppId);
                if (appName == "Unknown") return;
                game.FoundInSteamLibrary = true;
                game.SteamLibraryName = appName;
            }
```

The JSON I'm receiving looks like this:

```
{
"applist": {
    "apps": [
        {
            "appid": 1941401,
            "name": ""
        },
        {
            "appid": 1897482,
            "name": ""
        },
        {
            "appid": 2112761,
            "name": ""
        },
        {
            "appid": 1470110,
            "name": "Who's Your Daddy Playtest"
        },
        {
            "appid": 2340170,
            "name": "Melon Knight"
        },
        {
            "appid": 1793090,
            "name": "Blockbuster Inc."
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: You need to get the status code from the response.  Normal good status is 200 OK and bad response is a 400/500 status code.

Comment: 1. `SerializableAttribute` is not related to this code ...

Comment: The obvious troubleshooting step is to inspect `fileData` and make sure it contains valid JSON in the format you are expecting. This will narrow down the problem greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Your deserialization fails because your models have fields and [fields by default are ignored](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0#deserialization-behavior). You have two options:

- change fields to properties in your models

or

- annotate fields with `[JsonInclude]`

Comment: The doc example is not quite right. I edited my answer with the real response. Also even with your model and some changes to it to fit the response, it doesn't work. Throws an exception.

Comment: @MrSourceSys, you're right. I checked your code, and I found the root cause. I updated my answer.

Comment: @ Lukasz Szczygielek Basically you are right, but in my code the API response is never serialized, it is exclusively deserialized. In deserialization, it is the other way around, here fields are preferably ignored and resolved by properties.

Comment: @MrSourceSys still - for deserialization, fields are ignored by default too. I don't get the point of your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I played around with the model a bit more and found a solution.
Here is the matching model:

```
public class SteamAppList
{
    [JsonPropertyName("applist")]
    public Applist Applist { get; set; }
}

public class Applist
{
    [JsonPropertyName("apps")]
    public App[] Apps { get; set; }
}

public class App
{
    [JsonPropertyName("appid")]
    public long Appid { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).